# Enabling/disabling Ethernet interface via shell without root?

Tags: networking, shell

I am trying to create a shell script for enabling/disabling Ethernet interface on my unrooted Android 8.0 Set-Top Box. The box is connected both via Ethernet and Wifi - Ethernet has only IPTV vlan access, and Wifi has Internet access. My problem is that when Ethernet cable is connected, all traffic is routed through that interface, which means no Internet access for other apps (only IPTV access). That is why I am trying to automate Ethernet interface enable/disable when starting specific apps.

However, I cannot find a way to do this programmatically or via shell - all methods I tried require root access. Also, I know that a better way to enable both IPTV and Internet access would be by setting custom routing tables, but that also requires root access...

I have tried the following:

```
ifconfig eth0 down (requires root)
settings put secure ethernet_on 0 (requires reboot, which is a huge hassle)
```

Is there any other method to disable Ethernet interface which does not require root access? I can do it via Settings GUI, so I assume there must be a way to do it via terminal as well. Thanks.

Comment: Tried looking into that as well, to broadcast an intent, but could not find if there is a specific intent string for Ethernet enable/disable. Chipset is HiSilicon Hi3798M V200, ARM Cortex-A53.

Comment: there is some rooting guide for android 7 claiming that recovery is not signature enforcing. rename magisk.apk to update.zip and try to install from recovery, maybe you are lucky